# Ambient light sensor to a microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, operational-amplifier, analog, photodiode, phototransistor

I am looking to make a small sensor board for something at home. I am familiar with embedded systems but my electronics knowledge may not be the best.

For my situation, I would like to connect a simple ambient light sensor to a microcontroller. I am looking at a couple of options:

- [TEMT6000X01](https://www.vishay.com/docs/81579/temt6000.pdf)
- [TEMD6010FX01](https://www.vishay.com/docs/81308/temd6010.pdf).

On the microcontroller end I can see how to set it up, but what I am not sure is how to connect either one of these sensors to my microcontroller.

I have checked the current output for each but it is quite small (in uA) - I don't think this is something a microcontroller can pick up. Would I need an opamp for each? If so, which type would I need and how would it connect? Also I am not sure whether the phototransistor requires an opamp, after I've come across [this](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8688) (and this phototransistor has a higher output current compared to the photodiode.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a phototransistor, so it'll pass a current roughly proportional to light intensity.

[image]

Convert current to voltage with a resistor, add a small filter cap, and acquire with your micro's ADC. Resistor value depends on maximum current, which depends on maximum expected illumination, to get the full ADC range.

If you run out of ADC bits at low light, you can use an extra pin to make another range:

[image]

If the GPIO is set to output 0V, then you'll get a low resistance value. If the GPIO is set to input (without pullup or pulldown, best would be analog input mode) then only the higher value resistor is used, and you can pretend your ADC has more bits.

Note the phototransistor needs more than 0.1V across it to work properly, so you'll never get the full VCC on the output.

This type of sensor is built for low cost and not accuracy, so I don't think it is necessary to add a well polished circuit with an opamp. Note the current at 20 lux is between 3.5-16µA, which is quite a wide range. Fig.3 gives 400µA for 1000 lux, but the same dispersion should apply.

So basically, stick it under full sunlight if that's the maximum expected illumination, and pick a resistor value that works.

Answer (score 1):

If you are uncomfortable with analog, you can get digital ambient light sensors that connect over I2C and directly report a digital value for light level.  Lots of examples of interfacing these for Arduino's online.

For example, the [VEML7700](https://www.vishay.com/docs/84286/veml7700.pdf) integrates filtering, spectral correction, and temperature compensation, then outputs a calibrated lux value:

[image]

There are also [libraries for interfacing on Github](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_VEML7700) and well documented [breakout boards for sale](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-veml7700). Depending on what you are doing, this might be a lot easier then designing a custom circuit, especially if you want calibration or multiple sensors.

Answer (score 0):

*bobflux* fine phototransistor interface-to-microcontroller circuit requires an analog-to-digital (ADC), perhaps inside the microcontroller, or a separate ADC chip whose output is sent to a microcontroller.

For *ambient light sensing*, a slower speed-of-response is acceptable. Bobflux adds a parallel capacitor to slow down the relatively fast phototransistor current output. If fast response is desired (on the order of 0.1ms) his is the circuit to use.

For slower response wanted for *ambient light sensing*, a similar-looking circuit can directly interface to a **digital** microcontroller pin. An ADC is not required. The digital I/O pin should have the following characteristics:

- programmable as digital output, and digital input.
- schmitt input characteristic for digital input desirable.

[image: phototransistor-to-microcontroller interface schematic]

Any microcontroller includes facility to measure time in small increments. This could be a program loop that increments, or could be a programmable hardware clock counter - this is used to measure how long it takes to charge the 1nf capacitor up from **GND** to **logic 1** level. Charge time is proportional to phototransistor current.
In darkness, photocurrents are very small (perhaps tens of nanoamps) so that charge time is very long - perhaps seconds.
In bright light, photocurrents are much higher (perhaps tens or hundreds of microamps), so that charge time is very short.

A light measurement proceeds this way:

- the GPIO pin is switched to be an output pin, set to **logic low**, so that the capacitor is discharged to 0V.
- a short time is allowed (perhaps a few microseconds) for the capacitor to discharge to 0V.
- the GPIO pin is switched to be an input pin, timer reset to zero, timing started.
- when GPIO input pin rises to **logic high**, timer is stopped & stored.

Sensitivity to light can be changed by choosing a different capacitor value - a smaller capacitor increases sensitivity, reduces count value, shortens response time.
For very low light levels, leakage currents affect linearity, especially if ambient temperature can vary. The leakage current of the GPIO pin as well as leakage current of phototransistor are of concern.
One nice characteristic of this circuit is that light-level resolution improves at low light levels, since counter time is very high.

Comment: For ambient light sensing, would the phototransistor be better than the photodiode (TEMD6010FX01)? I am wanting to sense a specific artificial light which can be distinguished by the presence of certain level of IR radiation. But I only want this IR sensing to occur if ambient light is present (which is what I need the ambient light sensor for). I did have a look at differences between photodiode vs phototransistor (fast vs slow response) but I am not sure why a slower response would be better for ambient light sensing.

Comment: Photodiodes are potentially far faster than phototransistors, and phototransistors should be plenty fast enough to measure ambient light in a naturally lit static environment. To me, "ambient" implies natural, where fastest changing might be due to a cloud blocking the sun. In this capacitor-integrating circuit, you can get faster response time by choosing a smaller capacitor value, at the expense of resolution. That photodiode is far less sensitive than phototransistor. Be aware that both sensors have some IR sensitivity that your eye does not.